# ImageMagick Montage: Setting image size and page size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I am trying to use montage to print proxies for a card game I am developing (similar to Magic: the Gathering). I want the set the page size to letter, display four images per page, and have the images at 2.5 x 3.5 inches at 300 DPI.

I use the `-page letter` argument to get the right page size. I set `-tile 2x2` so that I have four images per page. I set `geometry +10+10` to get some space between the images.

However, montage resizes the images and they each take about 1/4 of a page, which is much bigger than what I want. I tried setting the pixels on `geometry`, for example, `-geometry 744x1039+10+10 -density 300` which is 2.5 x 3.5" in 300 DPI, however, that did not work -- the image sizes remain the same.

How can I set the page DPI to 300 and the size of each image in the montage to 2.5" x 3.5"?

Comment: Please share at least one, if not all four of your input images at representative size and dpi, along with the actual command you tried and also a mock-up of the expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your full command line.